# pagination in php and sql - appears me the same rows in every page

Tags: php, sql, pagination, rows

This is my code:

```
<?php

mysql_select_db("jvl_teste");

$per_page = 2;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM utilizadores");

$pages = ceil(mysql_result ($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizadores LIMIT $start, $per_page");

            echo '<table border="1" align="center">
            <tr class="d0">
                    <td align="center"><strong>Nome</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Idade</strong></td>
            </tr>';
            $rowColors = Array('#ffffff','#ffffcc'); $i= 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

            echo '<tr style="background-color:'.$rowColors[$i++ % count($rowColors)].';">';
                    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
                    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['idade'] . "</td>";
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<td align='center'><a href='detalhes.php?id={$id}'><img src='css/imagens/detalhes.png']}'/></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

if($pages >= 1){

for ($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++){

    echo '<a href="?pages='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';

}
}

            ?>
```

The problem is that in page 1, 2, 3.. etc appears me all the same first two results of the table rows in every page. What is the problem? Can you give me the solution please?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, your pagination links use the parameter `pages` but you're checking for a parameter called `page` (which obviously isn't there), so you're always defaulting to page 1.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but what should I change to put this thing working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@danielpsc says you have different name for your parameter in the links and in your PHP code, but they should be the same.

You need to change :

```
echo '<a href="?pages='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
```

To (remove the "s") :

```
echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
```